# how can I disable the resize into ui-layout-west?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="language" content="en" />




        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
        <!-- CUSTOMIZE/OVERRIDE THE DEFAULT CSS -->
        <style type="text/css">

        /* remove padding and scrolling from elements that contain an Accordion OR a content-div */
        .ui-layout-center , /* has content-div */
        .ui-layout-west ,   /* has Accordion */
        .ui-layout-east ,   /* has content-div ... */
        .ui-layout-east .ui-layout-content { /* content-div has Accordion */
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .ui-layout-center P.ui-layout-content {
            line-height:    1.4em;
            margin:         0; /* remove top/bottom margins from <P> used as content-div */
        }
        h3, h4 { /* Headers & Footer in Center & East panes */
            font-size:      1.1em;
            background:     black;
            border:         1px solid #BBB;
            border-width:   0 0 1px;
            padding:        7px 10px;
            margin:         0;
        }
        .ui-layout-east h4 { /* Footer in East-pane */
            font-size:      0.9em;
            font-weight:    normal;
            border-width:   1px 0 0;
        }

        </style>

        <!-- REQUIRED scripts for layout widget -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.layout.resizePaneAccordions-1.0.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="debug.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {

            myLayout = $('body').layout({
                west__size:         300


            ,   central_size: 400



            });
    $('#date').datepicker();
            // ACCORDION - in the West pane
            $("#accordion1").accordion({ size: 200,
                                            fillSpace:  true });
            //$("#accordion2").resizable(maxHeight= 100);

            //$("#accordion2").accordion({ autoHeight : false 

            //,fillSpace: true
            //,event: "click"});

    $('#tab').tabs();


        });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            $(".ui-layout-west").resizable({disabled: true});
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="ui-layout-north ui-widget-content" style="display: none;">

        North Pane
    </div>

    <div class="ui-layout-south ui-widget-content ui-state-error" style="display: none;"> copiright Fairy tail </div>

    <div class="ui-layout-center ui-widget-content " style="display: none;"> 
        <div id="tab">
        <ul>
             <li class="prova"><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Uno</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Due</span></a></li>

         </ul>
          <div id="fragment-1">
            <p>Testo 1</p>

         </div>
         <div id="fragment-2">
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...
         </div>

    </div>
    </div>  






    <div class="ui-layout-west " style="display: none;">
        <div id="accordion1" class="basic">

                <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <h5>West Pane</h5>
                    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. 
                        Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc.</p>
                    <p>Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. 
                        Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
                </div>

                <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <h5>Sed Non Urna</h5>
                    <p>Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus.
                        Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit,
                        faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.</p>
                    <p>Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</p>
                </div>

                <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
                        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede.</p>
                    <p>Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, 
                        magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>List item one</li>
                        <li>List item two</li>
                        <li>List item three</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames 
                        ac turpis egestas.</p>
                    <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
                        Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.</p>
                    <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
                        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Hi everybody, my problem is the following: I want that the user cannot resize the west panel: I checked the libraries but I couldn't figure it out. I'm using the jQuery layout, can somebody help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the layout plugin, it isn't the same as the resizable.

I can't copy paste properly due to my mobile device, but try changing your layout options to:

```
{
  west__size: 300,
  west__resizable: false,
  central__size
}
```